# Google Map API in my website

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm confused as to what Google Map API I will implement to my website regarding this plot.

1 - My admin user will set the address of a place on the google map (probably in textboxes)
2 - The users can view the place set by the admin and has already a marker in that specific place.

What are the differences between the v2 and v3?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: The Google Maps JavaScript API Version 2 has been officially deprecated as of May 19, 2010. The V2 API will continue to work until May 19, 2013, so there's only V3 right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use API V2 you need a key and now it's impossible to get one because API V2 has been officially deprecated as of May 19, 2010, just like [Marcelo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/408519/marcelo) said as a comment of your question.

You will need to use Api V3. Check the [Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) for more details.