# Google map API in my html website

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-api

hello I have a problem I wish to integrate ue google map in my site but I do not understand it appears when I update the page but then it disappears. In the console it says "no APIkey" but I did it several times. I followed the site: [developers.google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/)

but I do not understand where the error lies. I put the html part if a person understand the error please ! I also follow this topic [google api in my website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791870/google-map-api-in-my-website) but nothing appears !

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var ff = {
      lat: 50.638181,
      lng: 3.058227
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 17,
      center: ff
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: ff,
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDWdGA-ndsHMtR5-cdZrc5SHtfKKBG5Bfg&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: Run the snippet in your question. It tells you that you haven't activated the Maps API. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700182/apinotactivatedmaperror-for-simple-html-page-using-google-places-api

Comment: Thank you but i follow the topic and nothing appears again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console says:-
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#api-not-activated-map-error

so activate your google map API key under project.

Comment: How to activate a key? I follow the documentation. I select my project I generate a Key ! I don't put any restriction. I copy the Key but it's not working.

Comment: Steps
1. go to https://console.developers.google.com/
2. select project.
3. click on enable APIs And Services button
4. search for 'Google Maps JavaScript API'.
5. click enable

Comment: I have just check on Chrome mobile version and refresh many time but map doesn't disappeared.

Comment: Yes it's working now Thanks a lot ;) I clear data and it's working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Your API key is not activated. Make sure to generate a new one following the guide: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=de

Comment: Thank you but i follow the documentation and i suppose when i generate a key it's automatically activated...